# bundle exec rake asset:precompile error

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, css-float

When I run rake asset:precompile I get the following error:

```
Invalid CSS after "float:left": expected "{", was ";"
```

I have narrowed down the offending stylesheet file. I've been through it a million times and cannot seem to find the problem.

Can anyone clarify this error for me? Seems pretty straight forward but I searched for all float:left and found no problems.

could it be complaining about this format?

```
.label img {
  float:left;
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was a missing semicolon ABOVE the float:left;

Answer (score 0):

(You should remvoe it first and see if it fixes the error, then you will know the problem)

The CSS selector syntax is wrong.  Try this one

```
img.label { /*all img tags with class label*/
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I found the problem. It was a missing semicolon ABOVE the float:left;

Comment: You may want to write that answer, show how you fixed it and accept it as the best answer to your question.  Glad to know you got it sorted.